# Iterating over lists in a series to find similiiar elements in the list in python

Tags: python, list, duplicates, series

I have a series such as:

```
ID
1 [a,b,c,d,e]
2 [b,c,d,e,f]
3 [z,t,c,d,w]
```

I want to print out the common items in a list

```
output: [b,c,d,e]
```

Additionally, I'd like to know what ID they were a part of
output:

```
b: 1,2
c: 1,2,3
d: 1,2,3
e: 1,2
```

Comment: 1) format your input in a proper way; 2) post your initial code

Comment: Can you provide more details or examples? `c` and `d` appears in each list, but `b` and `e` only in 2 of 3, so its unclear in how much different list given elements must appear to be of interest to you. Say we have 100 lists, will be element appearing in 2 lists interesting to you or not? If not how many appearances you require?

Answer (score 1):

If you create a dictionary mapping the indexes to lists of characters you can get both parts of your answer:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
arr = [
    ['a','b','c','d','e'],
    ['b','c','d','e','f'],
    ['z','t','c','d','w']
    ]

for ind, l in enumerate(arr):
    for c in l:
        d[c].append(ind)
print(d)
```

`d` will be a dictionary like:

```
defaultdict(list,
            {'a': [0],
             'b': [0, 1],
             'c': [0, 1, 2],
             'd': [0, 1, 2],
             'e': [0, 1],
             'f': [1],
             'z': [2],
             't': [2],
             'w': [2]})
```

Items that appear in more than one list are found by looking at:

```
[k for k, v in d.items() if len(v) > 1]
# ['b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

You can index directly into the dict to find the indexes they are part of:

```
d['e']
# [0, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

let's try a counting approach, as we want a nice time complexity.

```
l1 = ['a','b','c','d','e']
l2 = ['b','c','d','e','f']
l3 = ['z','t','c','d','w']

# create an empty dictionary
count = dict()

# start your id counter
list_id = 1    

# iterate over the lists
for lst in [l1,l2,l3]:
    # iterate over each list, getting the char
    for char in lst:
        try:
            # try to append the list id to each corresponding char
            count[char].append(list_id)
        except:
            # if the char key doesn't exist in the dict, we add it as a list
            # containing our list id in which it was first found
            count[char] = [list_id]
    # increment our list id, as we finished looking on li
    list_id = list_id + 1

# print each char and list that contains more than one list_id
for key in count:
    if len(count[key])>1:
        print(key+': '+str(count[key]))
```

The output will be

```
b: [1, 2]
c: [1, 2, 3]
d: [1, 2, 3]
e: [1, 2]
```

Comment: A few notes: 1) You almost never need to manually increment an id field like that. Just make the loop `for list_id, lst in enumerate([l1,l2,l3], 1):` and you can remove the explicit initialization of `list_id` to `0`, and the explicit increment at the end of each loop. 2) Don't use bare `except`s; you expect a `KeyError`, catch only that, so you don't ignore `TypeError`s, `KeyboardInterrupt`s, etc. Or just use a `collections.defaultdict(list)` so you don't need the `try`/`except` at all, and can just unconditionally do `count[char].append(list_id)`.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow.

If I understand your problem, you could leverage a `defaultdict` for this:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

l1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
l2 = ['b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
l3 = ['z', 't', 'c', 'd', 'w']

output = defaultdict(list)

for l in [l1, l2, l3]:
    for item in l:
        output[item].append(l)

output = [{k: v} for k, v in output.items() if len(v) == 3]

print(output)
```

Outputs:

```py
[
  {'c': [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], ['b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'], ['z', 't', 'c', 'd', 'w']]},
  {'d': [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], ['b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'], ['z', 't', 'c', 'd', 'w']]}
]
```

Does this answer your question?

Comment: I think you need one more level of looping to get the individual characters.

Comment: He said 'common items', I'm assuming a list and comparing their items. If comparing single characters in string items, correct a third loop over each character in the `item` string is required.